# Multiply Factorial

Tags: factorial

I have a small comprehension gap with an easy equation. I have following term and I don’t know how to multiply it correctly. $ (n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!-1 $

One intermediate step must be. $ (n+2)(n+1)!-1 $

The result should be $ (n+2)!-1 $.

How do I multiply the term correct?
Is the attempt correct to multiply binomial series to $ (n+1)^2n!+(n+1)!-1 $?

It would awesome, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$$(n+1)\color{red}{(n+1)!}+\color{red}{(n+1)!}-1$$
$$=(n+1)![(n+1)+1]-1$$
$$=(n+2)(n+1)!-1$$
$$=(n+2)!-1$$

Comment: First you add $ (n+1)!+(n+1)! $ together?

Comment: @Taz: No, I factored $(n+1)!$ first, which is common as I showed with red. What remains from first statement is $(n+1)$ and $1$ from the second one, which will be $(n+2)$. Multiplying $(n+2)$ and $(n+1)!$, we get $(n+2)!$. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my formatting.

Comment: Where are you? +1

Comment: Oh Hi! @mrs thanks and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Gigili late vs tooooo late. 

Answer (score 5):

You would have no trouble with $(5)(n+1)!+(7)(n+1)!=(12)(n+1)!$ ($5$ apples plus $7$ apples equals $12$ apples.)

Maybe you would have a little trouble with $(5)(n+1)!+(n+1)!$, but not if you rewrite it as $(5)(n+1)! +(1)(n+1)!$ ($5$ apples plus $1$ apple equals $6$ apples).

Now let's look at $(n+1)(n+1)! +(n+1)!$. Rewrite this as $(n+1)(n+1)! +(1)(n+1)!$.
We have $n+1$ apples plus $1$ apple is $n+2$ apples, so the sum is $(n+2)(n+1)!$, which can be rewritten as $(n+2)!$.

Comment: +1 for two reasons: absurdly and casually turning the factorial into an apple (there is academic merit in that) and the coincidence I'm eating two apples.